# How to clear a variable of its content

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can you clear the contents of an array and a UIImageView? So that the array and the UIImageView aren't deleted, but instead "cleared" of what was stored in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the mutable array for 'clearing', call `removeAllObjects` method:

```
[array removeAllObjects];
```

Set `image` property for UIImageView to `nil` in order to 'clear' it:

```
imageView.image = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not alter an `NSArray`. `NSMutableArray` has a method called `removeAllObjects` for this, though.

An UIImageView does not *store* anything. You can remove any associated image from it by setting its `image` property to `nil`.